# Html.EditorForModel and Hiding element from Edit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using the following code to render an editor for my model using ASP.NET MVC 3, it works perfect, except for I don't want the user to see or edit the "Id" field in my object.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Your input has errors, please correct and try again") %>
    <%: Html.EditorForModel(Model)%>

    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
<% } %>
```

In my model for the ID Field I have the following

```
[Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
public int Id{ get; private set; }
```

Which granted is what I thought would work based on the description of the "AutoGenerateField" parameter.  However this isn't working.  I don't want to have to build the whole editor just for this one little oddity....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `[ScaffoldColumn(false)]` to hide fields

Comment: With the caveat that the field isn't just hidden, but omitted from the rendered view entirely. Thus it will not be returned as form data with POST requests.

Comment: I would look at Darin Dimitrov's solution if you need your ID bound to your post request.

Answer (score 20):

You could use the [`[HiddenInput]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.hiddeninputattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
[Display(AutoGenerateField = false)]
public int Id { get; private set; }
```

Comment: `HiddenInput` is probably the better choice over `ScaffoldColumn(false)` since the controller action is probably going to want to correlate whatever it is seeing with the database according to the submitted `Id`.