# Comparison of Data Annotations

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

What is the difference between the following three annotations:

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
[Display(Name = "")]
[Display(AutoGenerateField=false)]
```

There are related SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439272/why-is-there-a-displayautogeneratefield-false-and-a-hiddeninputdisplayvalu) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521204/difference-between-scaffoldcolumn-false-and-display-autogeneratefield-f), but I believe none that cover all three.  I've also seen an SO post that claims the [AutoGenerateField=false accomplishes nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189773/html-editorformodel-and-hiding-element-from-edit).  If so, then what is it for?  As for the other two annotations -ScaffoldColumn(false) and Display(Name="") - are they equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When marked with ScaffoldColumn(false)**

```
public class Hate
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string What { get; set; }

    public string Why { get; set; }
}

@model StrippingHtml.Models.Hate
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "What & Why You Hate";
}
<h2>
  What & Why You Hate</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Hate"))
{
  <div>
    @Html.EditorForModel()
  </div>
}
```

[image]

**When marked with Display(Name="")**

```
public class Hate
{
    [Display(Name="")]
    public string What { get; set; }

    public string Why { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

1. `ScaffoldColumn(false)`: Hides the display or editor field *only* when you use `@Html.DisplayForModel()` or `@Html.EditorForModel` (respectively), and *only* **so long as you are using the default display and editor templates**. If you override the built-in templates, you will need to add back in support for this attribute in your template.
2. `Display(Name="")`: Affects the text displayed as the label for `DisplayForModel`, `Label`, `LabelForModel`, and `EditorForModel`. In this case, the display name is set to an empty string, so that literally will be output as the label. That will not prevent the label from being generated.
3. `Display(AutoGenerateField=false)`: Appears to be unrecognized by any of the default templates or helpers, as you suggested.

No, 1 and 2 are *not* the same.